# Qt Error while building first project[Windows]

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I installed Qt Creator 4.1 Based on Qt 5.7.0 from https://www.qt.io/.

I tried to build a Qt Widgets Application, but I got the following error in the Console output:

```
Error while building/deploying project HelloWorld (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

What may be causing this problem?

I have searched in Google, but didn't find a solution to the problem. I am using Windows 8.1 x64 if that matters.

Comment: do you have a visual studio 2015 installed on your windows or vs 2015 compiler ?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015 installed, but I had only used it for C# applicaiton and I haven't tested it with C++.

Comment: I got this error too but when i don't install visual studio that have vs c++ you should install it

Comment: Yes, thank you. The solution was to install Visual Studio plugins for C++ through a Visual Studio wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install visual studio 2015 or vs c++ 2015 compiler so you can use vs compiler 2015 with Qt or use Qt with MinGW compiler